# Can a planar graph be drawn with all vertices on a straight line?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I have been repeatedly trying to prove and disprove the following:

> Can any planar graph, with $n$ vertices, be drawn such that the vertices are fixed at coordinates $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, ..., $(n-1,0)$ and all edges are half circles. (or convex/concave curves under/over the $y=0$ line).

Another way to express the problem, is whether we can always draw a planar graph, such that all vertices are on a straight line, and the edges are fairly simple (no zig-zag). There is (of course) no ordering on the vertices, so any permutation will do.

I can draw $K_4$, any subdivision and any planar graph I have tried, this way. However I haven't been able to find a proof.

I have tried many kinds of induction, e.g. triangulation based, but no luck. Do you have any ideas? (Or can you see a counter example?)

**Update:** As Nick wrote in the answer, the correct nomination appears to be "Book graph" and the following is a counterexample to the statement that all planar graphs are "2-bookable". Thanks Nick! [image: Counterexample]

Comment: If I recall correctly, this is true if and only if your graph is outerplanar.

Comment: @Nick, $K_4$ is not outerplanar, but it can be drawn with vertices on the line.

Comment: @Dmitry You are correct. I know this is a solved problem in the theory of book embeddings though; I'm trying to find the reference.

Comment: Ah, the condition I was looking for was subhamiltonian.

Comment: Outerplanar appears to be what you need for edges that only go above the line. I'm really impressed with how much stuff is on that Wikipedia article.

Comment: You surely know this, but for the benefit of future readers (I didn't notice it when I first read the question) I should mention that, in fact, every planar graph can be drawn with all vertices on a straight line, and the problem is to do this without any edges crossing this line. The proof is not hard: just take a point $X$ far from the graph, transform the area containing the graph by rescaling all lines through $X$ separately in the way all the vertices lie on a circle around $X$. Then straighten the relevant arc of the circle together with its neighborhood to get a required drawing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the condition you're imposing is equivalent to looking for a [book embedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_embedding) with book thickness at most 2. As proven in [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0095895679900212/1-s2.0-0095895679900212-main.pdf?_tid=25db0a18-8170-11e4-93e8-00000aacb362&acdnat=1418328120_e1e04de1cac3cd6d98e6e09a671a339e), this is the case if and only if your graph is a subgraph of a Hamiltonian planar graph. The [Goldner-Harry graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldner%E2%80%93Harary_graph) gives an example of a non-Hamiltonian, maximal planar graph. I do believe it is an example where your statement is false.

Comment: This is great! Thank you!