# Special Book Embeddings

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

I am taking a course on Topological Graph Theory, where we have looked into the topic of Book Embeddings. The particularly interesting ones were Book Embeddings with thickness 2. This essentially means we embed the graph so that all vertices lie on a straight line $l$, and the edges are arcs (simple curves) on one of the half planes created by this line with no crossings allowed. We know that only graphs who are subgraphs of a hamiltonian planar graph can be drawn this way.

My question is what happens if we allow the edges to cross the line on which the vertices lie. (if possible we also want the edges not to twist so we set a direction on the line $l$ and require the edges to monotonically increase in that direction). We still do not allow the edges to cross each other just the line. Can we then draw all planar graphs this way? Is this question already addressed somewhere?

Also what happens if we want to minimize the crossings on a certain graph. Let's say we only allow the edges to cross the line once and we want to use the least amount of edges that cross the line. Are there bounds on this?

Answer (score 2):

Any embedding can be represented according to your rules.

Represent your embedding as an embedding monotonic in the $x$ direction (Draw your embedding as a Fary embedding for example). Move the vertices a little bit so that no vertices have the same $x$ coordinates.
Cut the $x$ axis in $n$ segments corresponding to the projection of the $n$ vertices on the $x$ axis. For each interval $x_i, x_{i+1}$, for each point such that $x_i\leq x < x_{i+1}$, apply the following affine transformation:
$$(x, y) \mapsto (x, y - y_i + \frac{x-x_i}{x_{i+1}-x_i}(y_i-y_{i+1})$$
This transformation sends the vertices with abscissa $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ to the $x$-axis. It is easy to see that this transformation is continuous and preserves the monotony along the $x$ axis.

Comment: So if I understand correctly we apply a separate affine transformation to the consecutive intervals. How do we know that the 'edges' going between say $x_i$ and $x_j$ so that $j \neq i+1$ are going to stay edges, I mean their connections at the interval borders stay 'connected'. Also in this case we do not seem to know anything about the amount of crossings each edge can have (or do we?). Do you know anything about my second question?

Comment: @Kekule Sorry, I noticed that my transformation was ambiguous, I made more explicit what I had in mind.

Comment: I think you meant different signs because this way the $i+1$. point will not be on the x-axis. Also I still do not see how many edges will intersect the x-axis this way or how many times a single edge intersects the x-axis?

Comment: @Kekule I fixed it. An edge will cross the line if it is passing above a vertex and below another vertex in the original embedding. It can cross the line multiple times if it alternates passing above and below multiple vertices. For the minimization of crossing, it is possibly an much harder question (minimizing crossing for a planar graph is NP-hard, even though we have some bounds)

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4765965/383078) has some pictures.